# Advice on creating SQL indexes needed

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL query takes more than 13 secondss to execute as there are 40K records in master and 5000 rows in the second table.

Can any one tell the indexes to be created? I have created expiry-date and email as a combination index but does not work.

```
SELECT email,first_name,last_name,userid,PASSWORD,cons FROM MASTER 
WHERE expirydate <='2020-02-27' 
AND email NOT IN (SELECT (email) FROM bounce_emails_amazon)



EXPLAIN
1   PRIMARY MASTER  \N  ALL expdate_email,expemail.userid   \N  \N  \N  38228   60.75   Using where

2   SUBQUERY    bounce_emails_amazon    \N  index   email   email   103 \N  3567    100.00  Using index
```

Comment: Can you share the `EXPLAIN` for that query?

Comment: @Nico Haase Here is the EXPLAIN statement results added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
ALTER TABLE `master` ADD INDEX (expirydate);
ALTER TABLE `bounce_emails_amazon` ADD INDEX (email);
```

Then use the exclusion join query that @Alex suggested (I'll include it here):

```
SELECT 
  m.email,
  m.first_name,
  m.last_name,
  m.userid,
  m.PASSWORD,
  m.cons 
FROM MASTER m
LEFT JOIN bounce_emails_amazon b
ON b.email = m.email
WHERE m.expirydate <='2020-02-27' 
AND b.email IS NULL
```

The reason this is better is that the original query you showed using the subquery may scan the whole `bounce_emails_amazon` for every row of the outer query. By using a join, and adding the index to the `email` column, it will only look up the matching row.

Comment: the JOIN may be slightly faster, but the improvement seems small compared to the indexes.  In fact a query analyser with 40K in master and 1K rows in amazon_bounce split 53% between old and 47% to Join - really marginal

Comment: But it's not good if the 1K table must be fully scanned, potentially 40,000 times, right?

Comment: I have added EXPLAIN statement , wondering why the **key** is still not applied on **MASTER** table. However, the execution time is less than 0.10 seconds now.

Comment: Does the condition on `expirydate` match a large portion of the table? MySQL will skip using the index if the matches are too common.